# Could not find one byte memory leak in following code

Tags: c, memory-management, memory-leaks

```
int main(void)
{
    int byte;
    int i= 0,zj,di;
    int n = 0;
    char y[100];
    char e[100];
    char f1[100];
    int **arr;
    int *arr1;

    if(argc < 2)
    {
        printf("Input file does not exist:\n");
        printf("Enter arguments in the following manner:\n");
        printf("<./a.out> <input_file> <output_file>:\n");
        return 0;
    }

    fp1=fopen(argv[1],"r");

    if (fp1 == NULL ){
        printf("input file does not exist.\n");
        return EOF;
    }

    if(argc < 3 )
    {
        fp=stdout;
    }
    else
        fp=fopen(argv[2],"w");

    for(i=0;i<4;i++){
        fscanf(fp1,"%s",y);
        a = atoi(y);
        if(i==0)        zj = a;
        if(i==1)        di = a;
        if(i==2)        ck = a;
        if(i==3)        n =  a;
    }

    arr =(int**) memory_Malloc(n*sizeof(int*));
    for (i=0; i<n; ++i){
        arr[i] = memory_Malloc(2*sizeof(int));
    }

    arr1=(int*)memory_Malloc(di*sizeof(int));
    for (i=0;i<zj;i++){
        arr1[i]=0;
    }

    fgets(y,100,fp1);
    count=0;
    while (!feof(fp1)){
        fgets(y, 100, fp1);
        if(strlen(y)<=1)
            break;
        if(count>=zj)
            break;
        sscanf(y,"%s %s", e, f1);
        arr[count][0] = atoi(e);
        arr[count][1] = atoi(f1);
        count++;
    }

    for(i=0; i<n ; i++)
    {
        memory_Free(arr[i],2*sizeof(int));
    }
    memory_Free(arr,n*sizeof(int));
    memory_Free(arr1,di*sizeof(int));

    fclose(fp1);

    // intermediate code and then //

    fclose(fp);
}
```

[EDIT]

```
   1,600,000 bytes in 1 blocks are definitely lost in loss record 2 of 2
   ==15369==    at 0x43DC38B: malloc (vg_replace_malloc.c:149)
   ==15369==    by 0x8056080: memory_Malloc (memory.c:567) 
   ==15369==    by 0x804D51B: main (symbol.h:649)
   ==15369==
   ==15369== LEAK SUMMARY:
   ==15369==    definitely lost: 1,600,000 bytes in 1 blocks.
   ==15369==      possibly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks.
   ==15369==    still reachable: 96 bytes in 12 blocks.
   ==15369==         suppressed: 0 bytes in 0 blocks.
```

[EDIT]

```
   POINTER memory_Malloc(unsigned int Bytes) // same as malloc in standard C
   void memory_Free(POINTER Freepointer, unsigned int Size)
   int * PRECEDENCE
   PRECEDENCE P
   symbol.h 649 P = memory_Malloc(sizeof(int[symbol__MAXSIGNATURE]));
```

Comment: I cleaned up your posted code as bast as I could - it was a real mess - please try harder with code formatting in future if you want people to take the time to read your code and help you.

Comment: could you please explain what you've done and how you know about the leak?

Comment: @Mark I used valgrind for the above code. it shows 1 block memory loss. But it has been very hard me to find where the loss is.I have added valgrind output.

Comment: Please post the implementations of `memory_Free` and `memory_Malloc`.

Comment: You need to show the definitions of `memory_Malloc()` and `memory_Free()`.  Also, mark line 649 of `symbol.h` in the code listing, because it's this block that's been leaked.

Comment: @caf i have added the information you mentioned.

Comment: That is not the definition of `memory_Free()`.

Answer (score 2):

```
    arr1=(int*)memory_Malloc(di*sizeof(int));
    for (i=0;i<zj;i++){
        arr1[i]=0;
    }
```

- What is `memory_Malloc`?
- if `zj` is greater than `di`, you will be writing outside the `arr1`

  ```
  fgets(y,100,fp1);
  count=0;
  while (!feof(fp1)){
      fgets(y, 100, fp1);
  ```
- get 1 `y` from `fp1`, then begin loop, then get **another** `y` from `fp1`: you've just "lost" the first `y`

  ```
      if(count>=zj)
  ```
- Shouldn't this be `count>=n`? The array `arr` has space for `n` elements.

  ```
  memory_Free(arr,n*sizeof(int));
  ```
- What is `memory_Free()`?
- Why are you passing 2 arguments to it?
- `arr` size is not `n*sizeof(int)`: as you wrote in memory_Malloc, it is `n*sizeof(int*)`

Answer (score 2):

I think I've got it.

The `arr` size is not `n*sizeof(int)` = they're pointers, so should be `n*sizeof(int*)` instead.